# ggpot2: space axis ticks unevenly between equidistant values

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, axis

I have searched SO and other online sources to no avail.

Is there a way to scale an axis such that z-scores will better reflect the actual difference from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 2 (or any other equally spaced score)?

If I have an x-axis with z-scores ranging from -3 to 3 and axis ticks at every integer between, is there a way to have those axis ticks which are closer to 0 be spaced smaller than those that are farther?

Example:

```
-3        -2     -1  0  1      2          3
|----------|------|--|--|------|----------|
```

Am I missing some axis scaling method which accepts both the breaks as values but also the position of the breaks relative to the entire scale?

EDIT:

Maybe not quite a reprex, but this is the structure of the data and basic method of visualization:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    metric = c('metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3'),
    z_score = c(2, -1.5, 2.8)
  )

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = metric, y = z_score)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  ylim(-4,4)
```

The code above produces a plot where the z_score axis has evenly spaced breaks, whereas I would like the breaks to be "pulled" toward zero like I attempted to draw above.

Comment: Do you have reproducible example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe seems to correspond to a modulus transformation, but I don't know how to choose the correct parameters to get the exact transformation that you want.

Here is an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(
    metric = c('metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3'),
    z_score = c(2, -1.5, 2.8)
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = metric, y = z_score)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = modulus_trans(2),
                     limits = c(-4, 4),
                     breaks = c(-3:3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I hadn't played with `modulus_trans` to get it to work, nice. (Had I looked at its source earlier, I wouldn't have written my own below. Nice.)

Comment: This is simply the result of trial and error with transformations in the scales package. I wish I could sell this as a more intellectual effort, but alas!

Comment: Experimentation is plenty intellectual.

Answer (score 3):

The trick to this is to use a new `trans`formation object. There are several already defined in `scales::`, and the closest I found (though it is opposite, in a sense) is:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = metric, y = z_score)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans=scales::pseudo_log_trans(0.2, 2),
                     limits = c(-3, 3), breaks = -3:3)
```

[image: pseudo log transform]

But that has the opposite expansion I think you want. Since one way to see the opposite of `pseudo_log` would be `pseudo_exp`, and I didn't find one, here's an attempt:

```r
pseudo_exp_trans <- function(pow = 2) {
  scales::trans_new(
    "pseudo_exp",
    function(x) sign(x) * abs(x^pow),
    function(x) sign(x) * abs(x)^(1/pow))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = metric, y = z_score)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans=pseudo_exp_trans(),
                     limits = c(-3, 3), breaks = -3:3)
```

[image: pseudo exp transform]

Just play with the `pow=` argument to find the growth-rate you want in the axis.